# Docker COPY failed but no error during the build

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, containers

I try to push my index.html and styles.css files in my docker images. Here is my Dockerfile :

My directory :

```
Project
 - Dockerfile
 - index.html
 - styles.css
```

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY styles.css /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

The output :

```
Step 1/3 : FROM nginx:latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
Digest: sha256:2275af0f20d71b293916f1958f8497f987b8d8fd8113df54635f2a5915002bf1
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
 ---> 12766a6745ee
Step 2/3 : COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
 ---> 84fcd9b1e41f
Step 3/3 : COPY styles.css /usr/share/nginx/html/
 ---> 01a4fec8be28
```

But when I check on my container:

```
[tim@localhost Project ]$ sudo docker exec -it my_image bash
root@1495069379ec:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  docker-entrypoint.d  docker-entrypoint.sh  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@1495069379ec:/# cd /usr/share/nginx/html
root@1495069379ec:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
50x.html  index.html
```

I don't understand why my files are not on the /usr/share/nginx/html/ directory while the copy command seems to work...

There is some one to explain ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior -- if I build an image with your Dockerfile, the files show up as expected. Can you show your `docker build` command line and the *complete* output of that command?

Comment: ... as well as your `docker run` prior to `docker exec` command. In other words, please provide an [mcve](/help/mcve) with a full cyle from build to run.

Comment: With the given info (and as an example of an MCVE) [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/9270097b13e361a84f42fc07bd60d8e3)

Comment: As others are asking, did you run the image that you built?

Answer (score 0):

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM nginx:latest

ADD index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
ADD styles.css /usr/share/nginx/html/
```